# Как на время выключить все варнинги в файле VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, warning

VSCode отображает множество подчёркиваний C++ варнингов в файле. Можно ли на время выключить их, чтобы читать код, не отвлекаясь? Не нашёл такой кнопки, а городить хаки с изменением цветов подсветки на прозрачные не хочется.